# Change macOS display arrangement through command line / applescript?

Tags: macos, command-line, applescript, display

I have a 3 display setup at work with the following order (from left to right):

- MB Pro Retina 15" / internal
- Lenovo 23" / external
- Lenovo 23" / external

macOS Version: 10.13.6

Most likely when I reboot, the order is gone and I have to reset it through `System Preferences -> Display -> Arrangement`

Is there a way to change the arrangement through command-line or applescript?

Comment: I believe this is possible to do with AppleScriptObjC/JXA, but as I only have the one display, I've no means of testing.

Comment: This looks hopeful... https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/249447

Answer (score 2):

I got tired of that same problem and manage to reduce the 'displayPlacer' mentioned in the link of Mark Setchell to fix this particular problem to this :

```
#include <IOKit/graphics/IOGraphicsLib.h>
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    CGDirectDisplayID screenList[3];
    CGDirectDisplayID external1;
    CGDirectDisplayID external2;
    CGGetOnlineDisplayList(INT_MAX, screenList, NULL);

    if(CGDisplayIsMain(screenList[0])){
        external1 = screenList[1];
        external2 = screenList[2];
    }else if(CGDisplayIsMain(screenList[1])){
        external1 = screenList[0];
        external2 = screenList[2];
    }else{
        external1 = screenList[1];
        external2 = screenList[2];
    }


    CGDisplayConfigRef configRef;
    CGBeginDisplayConfiguration(&configRef);

    CGConfigureDisplayOrigin(configRef, external1, CGDisplayBounds(external2).origin.x, CGDisplayBounds(external2).origin.y);
    CGConfigureDisplayOrigin(configRef, external2, CGDisplayBounds(external1).origin.x, CGDisplayBounds(external1).origin.y);
    
    CGCompleteDisplayConfiguration(configRef, kCGConfigurePermanently);
}
```

My C was rusty it may not be very clean... It simply finds the 2 externals screens and reverse their position. It wouldn't be very hard to make preconfigured multiple positions if you change between two setups. It is in C but does the job.

Comment: Do you have a gcc/clang one-liner to go along with this wonderful little snippet?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have it I don't even remember coding this. As I read it I see that there is probably an error at the last else in the 'mainScreen detection' conditions
        external1 = screenList[1];
        external2 = screenList[2]; //should be screenList[0]; I think

Comment: `clang -o swap -f CoreGraphics swap.c` might work just fine